# How does the right-shift operator work in a python print statement?

Tags: python, grammar

I've seen someone using "print" with ">>" to write stuffs into a file:

```
In [7]: with open('text', 'w') as f:
   ...:     print >> f, "Hello, world!"
   ...:

In [8]: !type text
Hello, world!
```

How does it work? When should I use this instead of just using the "write" method?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement

> print also has an extended form,
>   defined by the second portion of the
>   syntax described above. This form is
>   sometimes referred to as “print
>   chevron.” In this form, the first
>   expression after the >> must evaluate
>   to a “file-like” object, specifically
>   an object that has a write() method as
>   described above. With this extended
>   form, the subsequent expressions are
>   printed to this file object. If the
>   first expression evaluates to None,
>   then sys.stdout  is used as the file
>   for output.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that this extended form no longer exists in Python 3, so new code should probably avoid it.

Comment: This isn't actually the `>>` operator in this case; the parser handles it specially as part of the `print` syntax.