# Python operators with other meanings (like the print chevron)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, operators

There are a number of questions on SO about Python's print chevron, which uses the same token as one of the bit-shift operators to send `print`'s output somewhere other than stdout:

```
print >> sys.stderr, "foo"
```

From [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18837450/2829764):

> The >> token is not actually an operator here; it's part of the syntax of the print statement, as documented [here](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement).

Are there other operators in Python 2 that also perform non-operator functions? What about Python 3 (in which the print chevron is gone)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown in the [grammar](https://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.9/file/753a8f457ddc/Grammar/Grammar), only `>>`, `*` (positional expansion), and `**` (keyword expansion) have non-operator meanings. Python 3.x (as of 3.4.x) retains the last two, and adds none. Python 3.5 will [add](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/) a matrix multiplication operator (`@`) as well as its augmented assignment (`@=`).

Comment: And before anyone complains, `@`, `,`, and `:` have no operator meanings, and `.` has no non-operator meaning (other than float literals, but that doesn't count).